# How to override update function of a custom model in Odoo 11

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

I want to create a `customer_number` in the format of `cust<id>` (For example, cust001, cust004,.. ) using the `id`. When I use the `create()` function it returns the `id` of the record. So I decided to update the record with my `customer_number` using the `id` of the record. The following code is in the `create()` function.

`res = super(lot_number, self).write(vals)`

I want to create a customer number using the `id` of the record. I would really appreciate some help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @api.model
>
> def create(self, vals):
>
> ```
> res = super(lot_number, self).create(vals)
>
> res.customer_id = 'cust'+str(res.id)
>
> return res
> ```